# Is there is any plugin for eclipse to save my collapsed methods

Tags: eclipse

For example I collapsed two method in class x and when I close this class and reopen it again these methods appeared without collapsing ,

How can I save my collapsed methods in eclipse ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. Been waiting for this for years myself.

Comment: When will they do this ?!

Comment: Who are "they"? Eclipse is open-source and patches are welcome I'm sure.

Comment: How can I do a patch ?